# How to convert windspeed between Beaufort Scale and M/S and vice versa in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, formula

I am trying to create a function to convert metres per second (m/s) to [Beaufort scale](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale) in Javascript. I can do this using a series of if statements, but it I would much prefer to replace this with the formula to dynamically calculate this for me.

This is what my research has enabled me to achieve so far:

```
function beaufort(ms) {
    ms = Math.abs(ms);
    if (ms <= 0.2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (ms <= 1.5) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (ms <= 3.3) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (ms <= 5.4) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (ms <= 7.9) {
        return 4;
    }
    if (ms <= 10.7) {
        return 5;
    }
    if (ms <= 13.8) {
        return 6;
    }
    if (ms <= 17.1) {
        return 7;
    }
    if (ms <= 20.7) {
        return 8;
    }
    if (ms <= 24.4) {
        return 9;
    }
    if (ms <= 28.4) {
        return 10;
    }
    if (ms <= 32.6) {
        return 11;
    }
    return 12;
}
```

I would like to replace this with a function that automatically calculates using the correct formula. Doe anyone know how this can be achieved without multiple if statements or switch case?

Comment: http://www.csgnetwork.com/windspeedconv.html

Comment: @mplungjan - I am asking how to achieve the conversion in javascript. I know there are many online convertors. But this is not what I am asking for.

Comment: I know, just read the source of the page I posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after reading several articles there seems to be a formula to calculate Beaufort to and from m/s. I will answer my own post with a couple of functions that I have made.

Calculate m/s to beaufort:

```
function msToBeaufort(ms) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.cbrt(Math.pow(ms/0.836, 2)));
}

msToBeaufort(24.5);
output: 10
```

Calculate beaufort to m/s:

```
function beaufortToMs(bf){
    return Math.round(0.836 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bf, 3)) * 100)/ 100;
}

beaufortToMs(3)
output: 4.34
```

I know its a rare topic, but hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale#Modern_scale) msToBeaufort(0.4) should be scale 0, but your formula gives 1.

Also, you probably should round ms to only 1 decimal position as the scales in wiki have just one digit precision for m/s unit